# flash banner is coming through my fancybox image

Tags: flash, fancybox

My flash banner pops through my fancybox image. How can I keep the fancybox image on top of the flash banner? I have included my flash banner coding:

```
<embed src="Car Banner.swf" width="271" height="169" quality="high" flashvars="flashlet={imageLinkTarget pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent”> </embed>
      </object>
      </noscript>
    </p>
    <p align="left" class="fancybox">
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the wmode to transparent?

Comment: I would say `wmode` to `opaque` (of your flash banner)

Comment: Yes, I tried switching between opaque and transparent still does the same thing.